# Finding Equilibrium Points of Dynamical System

Tags: matrix-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

I am wondering how to find the equilibrium points from these $2$ equations

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} & =
0.4x\left(1 - \frac{x}{1000} + \frac{y}{1000}\right)
\\[2mm]
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} & =
0.1y\left(1 + \frac{x}{1000} - \frac{y}{500}\right)
\end{align}

- From the $2$nd equation, the $y$ value I got is $y = 0$ and
  $x = -1,000$
- and from the $1$st equation I got $x = 0$ and
  $y = -1,000$

So I am wondering is it use the $1$st equation to get the
$\left(x,y\right)$ value or use the $2$nd equation to get the $\left(x,y\right)$ value ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to simultaneously find the zeros of

$$0.4x\left(1-\frac{x}{1000}+\frac{y}{1000}\right) = 0\\ 0.1y\left(1+\frac{x}{1000}-\frac{y}{500}\right) = 0$$

We can see that each equation is of the form $a b = 0$, so each of those being zero, will satisfy the equation and we just need for them to do that **simultaneously** for both equations.

We can set $x = 0$ in the first equation and substitute that in the second equation

$$0.1y\left(1+\frac{0}{1000}-\frac{y}{500}\right) = 0$$

From this we get two $y$ values of

$$y = 0, 500$$

We can set $y = 0$ in the second equation and substitute that in the first equation

$$0.1x\left(1-\frac{x}{1000}+\frac{0}{1000}\right) = 0$$

From this we get two $x$ values of

$$x = 0, 1000$$

So that takes care of the $x$ and $y$ terms by themselves. Now, ignoring that term, we have

$$0.4\left(1-\frac{x}{1000}+\frac{y}{1000}\right) = 0\\ 0.1\left(1+\frac{x}{1000}-\frac{y}{500}\right) = 0$$

Solving the first for $y$

$$y = x - 1000$$

**Note:** We could have solved for $x$ or also used the 2nd equation - try it.

Substituting that into the second

$$\frac{1}{10} \left(-\frac{1}{500} (x-1000)+\frac{x}{1000}+1\right)=0$$

Solving this gives $x = 3000$, which means $y = 2000$.

So, our solution set is

$$(x, y) = (0,0), (0,500), (1000, 0), (3000, 2000)$$

We can use a contour plot to see these points of intersection

[image]

Comment: Oh i see. Cause i gotten (0,500) and (3000, 2000). The other 2 points of (x,y) i did not know must do it simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks so much. I understood it !

Comment: And surprisingly, I found only one of them is stable...can we conclude this from paramteric eqns?

Comment: The system would have to be analyzed, Jacobian, eigenvalues of Jacobian at each critical point, Phase portrait..